# Preload a bunch of images, and return when all of them are complete

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Here is a relatively code example. Basically what I am trying to do is preload a few images (hence the for loop). The preloading works, but I don't know when it is complete. I know there are listeners but I am not sure how those work

Is there a solution to only return from this method when all the images in the for loop are completely loaded. Does that make sense?

```
public void method(){
    final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sources.size(); i++) {


                        final ReadableMap source = sources.getMap(i);
                        final GlideUrl glideUrl = FastImageViewConverter.glideUrl(source);
                        final Priority priority = FastImageViewConverter.priority(source);
                        Glide
                                .with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                                .load(glideUrl)
                                .priority(priority)
                                .placeholder(TRANSPARENT_DRAWABLE)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                                .preload()
                                .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
                                    @Override public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    @Override public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        // easy
                                        return false;
                                        // impossible?
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best answer but probably fits into your case :)

```
public void method(){
    final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int counter = sources.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < sources.size(); i++) {


                        final ReadableMap source = sources.getMap(i);
                        final GlideUrl glideUrl = FastImageViewConverter.glideUrl(source);
                        final Priority priority = FastImageViewConverter.priority(source);
                        Glide
                                .with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                                .load(glideUrl)
                                .priority(priority)
                                .placeholder(TRANSPARENT_DRAWABLE)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                                .preload()
                                .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
                                    @Override public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        counter--;
                                        if counter == 0 {
                                            return your result here
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    @Override public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        counter--;
                                        if counter == 0 {
                                            return your result here
                                        }
                                        return false;
                                        // impossible?
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

as you know how many images you want to pre-load, maybe you can set a counter and in `onResourceReady` you would increment this counter. Once it reaches the number of images you want to pre-load, you're done and you can go on executing other stuff

Comment: ahh okay, could do you this all within the same method though? just not sure how this would work

Comment: @Umair Aamir describes it well in his answer